# receiving WebDriverError: No System TLS while trying to protractor scripts from CentOS

Tags: protractor

I'm using ***node verison v6.14.1,protractor Version 5.3.1, on CentOS.***

**Full Message:**

> E/launcher - No System TLS [06:43:05] E/launcher - WebDriverError: No
>   System TLS
>       at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
>       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
>       at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7) From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
>       at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
>       at createDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
>       at Builder.build (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
>       at Local.getNewDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
>       at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
>       at q.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
>   [06:43:05] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199 sh-4.2# vi
>   config.js

Comment: would it be possible to post more details? like Chrome Version, and your conf.js file? if you cannot post the whole conf file just paste the Capablities section of the Conf.js

Comment: From the Error i can see that your session is not even started so need to investigate more on that. There might be several things which is preventing you. And also tell me whether are you trying to run CentOS in Non GUI mode.